# How to override the `project.build.finalName` Maven property from the command line?

Tags: maven, command-line, maven-3

I have the following plain pom running by Maven 3.0.4.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

</project>
```

I am trying to override default settings in command line like this:

```
mvn -Dproject.build.finalName=build clean package
```

But this this is ignored, and I get `test-1.0.jar`. I've tried to change another properties, like outputDirectory, directory, artifactId, but also failed.

What is the proper way to do this thing?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

See [Introduction to the POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)

finalName is created as:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
</build>
```

One of the solutions is to add own property:

```
<properties>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
</properties>
<build>
    <finalName>${finalName}</finalName>
 </build>
```

And now try:

`mvn -DfinalName=build clean package`

Comment: Is that the only way to do that? What if I can't make changes to the POM file?

Comment: You can not override `artifactId` and `version`. So you can create next project add include in dependencies current one only. Then you can make what you want.

Comment: I need to override `finalName` through command line without changing POM. Is that doable?

Comment: Ok, it is unavailable, because you only can override user-defined properties, not Maven Properties because they are properties of Model class. The solution is described in the answer.

Comment: For overriding multiple parameters, use multiple -D flags. If anyone is wondering.

Comment: Additionally, if the property you are trying to override has periods, you might need to enclose it in single quotes like: `mvn '-Dproject.build.finalName=build' clean package`

Comment: @Xantix Why would you need to to this? Do you have a shell for which dots are special characters?

Comment: @scravy It gives an error like: "[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".build.finalName=build". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in...".  FWIW, I use Powershell.

Comment: The maven assembly plugin has a property called skipAssembly. The reference says that the user property for this is "assembly.skipAssembly". [ref] (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html)

I've set it to true in the pom. I've tried setting this false on the command line but it gets ignored.

`mvn -Dassembly.skipAssembly=false clean install`

Any thoughts?

Comment: How to move this war in artifactory ?

Comment: Just `mvn deploy`?