# Setting properties in maven JAR when building

Tags: java, maven

I have a regular Maven project. I would like to set certain properties/variables in the JAR when building using `mvn package`, so that certain information can be picked up from individual JAR files.

For example, I could use:

```
mvn package -DbuildId=200
```

... and I would like to see this information stored (`buildId = 200`) stored in some file generated by maven. I know for a fact that certain properties are stored by Maven at build-time (for example, the files in `META-INF/maven`).

Is this possible without modification of the POM file, and without adding extra plugins? If so, what arguments do I need to pass?

Comment: Without modifying any POM file, how do you intend Maven to know there is a `buildId` system property to read and written somewhere?

Comment: @Tunaki I was thinking of just setting some variable in a file when building. That information could be used by some 3rd-party application that reads it.

Comment: But why would you expect Maven to even know there is a variable to write somewhere? You need to modify your build to take it into account.

Comment: @Tunaki Hmm yeah, I get your point. What I am suggesting is to (kinda) add <property> values while building the application, in the command line. The example I gave (-DbuildId) does not and is not expected to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876165/how-to-override-maven-property-in-command-line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override maven property in command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876165/how-to-override-maven-property-in-command-line)