# Maven exec:java override system properties defined in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I have this in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
    <systemProperties>
      <systemProperty>
        <key>someKey</key>
        <value>someValue</value>
      </systemProperty>
    </systemProperties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When running this from command line, I sometimes want to override the above `someKey:someValue`. I tried this:

```
mvn exec:java -DsomeKey=someOtherValue
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to dot this?

Comment: Does the answer of this post helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876165/how-to-override-maven-property-in-command-line

Comment: @Villat Yeah I tried that (`mvn exec:java -DsomeKey=someOtherValue`), but it doesn't seem to be working with `exec:java` for some reason.