# How to override profile property from command line

Tags: java, maven

I see we can pick a profile by maven command

```
mvn test -P testenv
```

How can override a property like - remote-webdriver I want to pass a URL for this. How can I do this with maven command

pom.xml contains below:

```
<profile>
            <id>testenv</id>
<properties>
                <test-id>1</test-id>
                <test-report>false</test-report>
                <testrail-close-testrun>false</testrail-close-testrun>
                <test-create>false</test-create>
                <environment-var>testenv</environment-var>
                <remote-webdriver>null</remote-webdriver>
            </properties>
        </profile>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override maven property in command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876165/how-to-override-maven-property-in-command-line)

Comment: Though I am working with profiles, I see that solution is working by proving -D  thanks!

Comment: Just in case someone else stumbles onto this question, everything that's within a `<property>` tag can be set using `-Dproperty=value`. Profile properties are no different.

Comment: Usually profiles are a smell in your build....